# Reducing representation of floating point numbers to 16 bits

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I'd like to simulate computations happening on an embedded device. Therefore, I'd like to reduce the representation of floating point numbers to 16bits. What would be the easiest way to do it? I'd like to still be able to use libraries such as numpy. Is there a way to reduce the accuracy for these libraries? Or can I create some virtual environment which just allows 16-bit floats?

I mostly plan to use libraries that are built on top of numpy. So it would be handy to still be able to use the libraries but just reduce the precision trough some global setting.

Comment: Do you mean half-precision IEEE with 5 bit exponent, 10 bit mantissa?

Comment: Cannot you use `dtype=float16` with NumPy?

Comment: I don't know exactly yet. So i just said 16 bits in order to have an example of how to do it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by *"libraries such as numpy"*? In your comment on Burhan Khalid's (now deleted) answer you mention Theano and Keras. Theano doesn't support a 16 bit float type ([see here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#all-fully-typed-constructors)).

Comment: I see that Theano doesn't support it. Is there a way to fool theano by reducing the precision in the pyhton execution environment somehow? So that if I use a library i can just use it the same way as before, but all float computations will happen with 16 or 32 bit precision?

Comment: No. You can truncate the precision of numpy arrays by casting them to `np.float16`, but Theano would still have to use 32 or 64 bit floats internally. Could you explain a bit more about what architecture you're targeting? It's more than likely that numpy and Theano won't cross-compile for it anyway.